# Adding html link in select list

Tags: theming

I want to add the below code to a node in full html text format in drupal7 website. The idea is to select one of the link in select list after selection relevant link is opened.

```
<form name="jump1">
<select name="myjumpbox"`
OnChange="location.href=jump1.myjumpbox.options[selectedIndex].value">
<option selected>select a link...
<option value="http://rediff.com">link1
<option value="http://google.com">link2
<option value="http://yahoo.com">link3
</select>
</form>
```

but once an option is selected it is not doing anything. It is not implementing 3rd line of this code.

Comment: The code above is missing closing tags, e.g.: </option>, </select>. Is that just a typo on DA or is the actual form missing them?